# How the Session works in browsers

Tags: django, django-views, backend

I have this Django code which get the "msg" from the session and save it to a variable msg then check if the msg is true if true it will delete it from the session but still the msg variable contains the old value. I know i can set the msg to False in the if block but is there another way of doing this

```
def get(self, request):
    msg = request.session.get("msg", False)
    if msg:
        del request.session["msg"]
    context = {"message": msg}
    return render(request, "guess_form.html", context)

def post(self, request):
    guess = request.POST.get("guess")
    msg = checkGuess(guess)
    request.session["msg"] = msg
    return redirect(request.path)
```

I Want to make the msg to be empty when the app runs for the first time
the msg meaning the variable